# How to make an input field inaccessible through keyboard Tab

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility

I have an input field that is accessible using the `Tab` key.

```
<label class="radioButtonCard-label" for="myInput"> 
<input
   id="myInput"
   type="radio" 
   name="radio"
 />
```

**Requirement**: I want to skip this input field when navigating using keyboard keys.

I tried setting `tabindex` but that doesn't work with input fields.

Edit: I'm using ReactJs. Adding `tabindex` to input tag gives me the following error:

```
Type '{ id: string; type: string; name: string; checked: boolean; tabindex: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'tabindex' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: why can't you use the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on *why* do you need it? It seems, you are trying to break accessibility of your product.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I tried setting `tabindex="-1` on input field using jquery and it worked. (imagine using jquery in 2020)

`$('#myInput').attr('tabindex', '-1');`

I don't know why I can't apply this `tabindex` attribute directly to input field in React.

Comment: Try `tabIndex`, notice the uppercase I.